# SyntaxError with pymongo and $ne : null

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

this is my code :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
from pymongo.connection import Connection
from pymongo.master_slave_connection import MasterSlaveConnection


database = 'toto'
collection = 'logs'

master = Connection(host="X.X.X.X", port=27017)
slave1 = Connection(host="X.X.X.X", port=27017)
con = MasterSlaveConnection(master, slaves=[slave1, master])

db = getattr(con,database)

#host_name.append("getattr(db,collection).distinct( 'host_name' )")
#print host_name[1]

hosts = db.logs.distinct( 'host_name' )

services = db.logs.distinct("service_description" , { "service_description" : { $ne : null } } )

#print hosts
print services
```

I got this error :

```
File "./rapport.py", line 23
    services = db.logs.distinct("service_description" , { "service_description" : { $ne : null } } )
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why i can't use `"$ne : null"` in my code? I don't understand because when i execute this query `"db.logs.distinct("service_description" , { "service_description" : { $ne : null } } )"` directly in mongodb it works.

I also tried this but it doesn't work :

```
services = db.logs.distinct("service_description", { "service_description" : { "$ne" : None } } )
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote the `$ne` and use `None` instead of null.
Pymongo uses dicts as parameters.

```
asdf = "something"
{ asdf: "foo"}
```

is a valid declaration, using `"something"` as key.

If you compare that with

```
{$ne: "foo"}
```

the interpreter expects a variable name as first entry, and `$ne`is invalid.

Also, `null`is not predefined in Python, so use `None` instead.

Combined with the fluid interface in pymongo, your query should be:

```
db.logs.find({"service_description": {"$ne" : None}}).distinct('service_description')
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to quote $ne and use None but it doesn't work "services = db.logs.distinct("service_description", { "service_description" : { "$ne" : None } } )" i got this error "TypeError: distinct() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: That is because in pymongo the interface is more fluent. You need to use `find(<query>).distinct(<key>)`, cf. (documentation)[http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=distinct#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct]

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am a newbie. Thx